# ClassNotFoundException with Oracle Type4 Drivers

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I am not using any IDE, writing my program on notepad and running through command prompt.
I have Oracle 10g enterprise edition installed and path to ojdbc14.jar in this version is like this:

```
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\jdbc\lib
```

I have added the Classpath as follows:

```
. ; C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar;
```

and yet, it gives `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` at `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Any idea?

Comment: Since you haven't posted your code, why don't we just take some guesses on what you have written?

Comment: I think adding only `C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\jdbc\lib` to the classpath should work.

Comment: Please can you post the relevant code and the way you tried to execute?

Comment: @Annjawn No it doesn't, a classpath entry is either a jar (or zip) with classes, or a folder with classes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ummmm.....in my comment I mentioned adding the folder (lib) with all the classes/libraries (this particular folder is from the Oracle installation). Works perfect on my PC. Adding every class/library by name (with jar/zip) to the classpath is not a very clever thing to do. Saying again, in case you missed it, lib is a folder.

Comment: @Annjawn If lib doesn't contain classes (but only jars with classes), then adding the folder to the classpath doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am not sure where you're coming from, but with default Oracle installation this setting works just fine for me. And when I say setting, it's at Windows environment variable level.

Comment: @Annjawn Beside the fact that the `CLASSPATH` environment variable is hardly used for real applications (as they either use `-jar` or `-classpath`), I refer you to the [documentation on the classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) for an explanation on how it works.

Comment: I tried all of it and it did not work at all. Is it possible that it does not work particularly on windows 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, and assuming the jar file exists at the given path, this

```
. ; C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar;
```

Should be

```
java -cp .;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar
```

**Note** it may not contain spaces. See also the [Essential Classes > The Platform Environment > PATH and CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Comment: I am supposed to add path to jar along with java -cp in the environment variable? Actually I wanted to set the permanent path and as far as I know we can use java - cp in command prompt only, Isn't that?